# Are all 32 bit floats exactly represented as f64?

Tags: casting, floating-point

Can all  IEEE 754 32 bit floating point numbers be represented exactly by a 64 bit floating point number? Stated another way, is a cast from f32 to f64 ever rounded?

Comment: What about those 2 formats makes you think it *would* be rounded?

Comment: Nothing in particular, just needed a sanity check. Also, I couldn't find this question and answer stated anywhere so now it's in the public record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can all IEEE 754 32 bit floating point numbers be represented exactly by a 64 bit floating point number?

Yes.  All numeric values of [binary32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) are in [binary64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format).

> Stated another way, is a cast from f32 to f64 ever rounded?

Not usually.  Various language like C allow intermediate 32-bit FP calculations to employ wider math and so a *cast* may narrow (round) results.  Yet if the value was truly  f32, no rounding error would occur going to f64.

---

Aside:
The [Not-a-number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN) payload of a binary32 is 23 bits and that is fully encodable as a binary64, yet the detailed meaning of those is implementation dependent.